# Arithmetic mod 1

Tags: ergodic-theory

I was reading the news and a topological data paper was out about arithmetic mod 1, it had persistence graphs of some functions. Isn't arithmetic mod 1 only with decimals? Why is it so popular in ergodic theory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't arithmetic mod 1 only with decimals?

This arithmetic has nothing to do with the representation.  One builds equivalence classes
$$
x\equiv y \qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad x - y = k\cdot1\ \text{ for some } k\in\Bbb Z
$$
i.e. one only considers sets of numbers, and in each set the numbers differ by an integral amount.  You can use the interval $[0,1)\subset\Bbb R$ to uniquely represent these classes, and you can define well-defined operations $+$, $-$, $\times$ as obvious. Computation is *"perform operation and throw away the integral part"*. For example:
$$ 1\equiv 2$$

$$ \tfrac13 -\tfrac12\equiv\tfrac56$$

$$ 4\cdot0.5 \equiv 2\cdot0.5 = 0.5 + 0.5\equiv 0$$

The last means there are [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor), and you cannot define division for rational numbers mod 1 in a sensible way.

Bit more intuitive is to represent that ring as rotations of a circle by some angle $\phi$:

$$
\phi\equiv \psi \qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \phi - \psi = k\cdot2\pi\ \text{ for some } k\in\Bbb Z
$$

The dynamics is already non-trivial, it's the [Julia-set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set) for $z\mapsto z^2$, see for example [Dynamik von *z→z²*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia-Menge#Dynamik_am_Beispiel_f(z)_=_z%C2%B2).

Answer (score -1):

I think $mod \: 1$ is simply defined as follw:
$0$ if $n$ is an intger else {n} (where $\{\}$ is the decimal part) for $n$ mot an integer.